# how to get access a chart by name

Tags: vba, charts, ms-word

Using Word VBA, is it possible to access/get a reference to a chart object using the chart name?

In the Word interface, you can open the "selection pane", and specify a name for a chart. I would like to use that name property to access the chart in VBA.

If I can't use the name, I have to get a reference through a more cumbersome route by locating the chart as part of a range's InlineShape collection.

```
Set MyChart= wrdApp.Selection.InlineShapes(1).Chart
```

But that is very tedious, so it would be great to be able to navigate straight to the chart based on the name...

Comment: One possibility would be to select the InlineShape and insert a bookmark "around" it. Then you can pick it up through the bookmark: Doc.Bookmarks("name").Range.InlineShapes(1)

Answer (score 1):

InlineShape-objects do not have a name property. If you convert them to shape objects they do, but you would still have to address them with `InlineShapes(index)` for the conversion:

```
Sub ShapeTest()
    Dim oShp As Shape

    If ThisDocument.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
        Set oShp = ThisDocument.InlineShapes(1).ConvertToShape
        MsgBox "Shape name = " & ThisDocument.Shapes(oShp.Name).Name
    End If

    Set oShp = Nothing
End Sub
```

(The sample is quite meaningless, but you get the idea)

**EDIT**:

Just checked the [online documentation for InlineShape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff840794%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and it seems that the `InlineShape` object as a `Name` property in Word 2013 and later. Which version are you running? I only have access to Word 2010 where my ansewer above is true.

Comment: IMO your original post is correct. Caution is valuable, but AFAICS the online documentation is wrong. "Name" is listed as a Method (which would be unusual for Word/VBA) and there is no link to any further info. In the Object browser in Word 2016 VBA (but I have not checked 2013), there is no Name member (even with hidden members displayed). The .Item member of the InlineShapes collection defines the index as "As Long", which pretty much rules out a string Index value. In collections where both types of index are possible, it's generally just defined as (Index), not (Index As Long)

Comment: @bibadia OK, thanks for the information! Your comment makes sense, the documentation probably needs to be updated.